# MultiSelection not working in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have problem in ListView MultiSelection.

Here is my code :

```
   private ICommand _excludeCurveCommand;


    public ICommand ExcludeCurveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_excludeCurveCommand == null)
                _excludeCurveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(param => this.ExcludeCurveExecuted(param));

            return _excludeCurveCommand;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executed event for ContextMenu --> Remove click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">param is FolderItemViewModel bound as CommandParameter</param>
    private void ExcludeCurveExecuted(object param)
    {

        ICollection<object> curves = param as ICollection<object>;
        int count =  curves.Count;
    }



 < Button Content="Exclude" Command="{Binding ExcludeCurveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=lstView}" .../>

< ListView Name="lstView"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectionMode="Extended" ..../>
```

Here i used shift and selected from first four items. But in ExcludeCurveExecuted method i getting some random counts always. What is the issue in this.

**EDIT:**
* I don't wantto go with IsSelected flag in ViewModel

Comment: I don't know what is happening. After i re-factor the code, its working as expected. But i don't find any major changes. hhhm no clue. Any way its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems that you have have `ListView` UI virtualization enabled, as it enabled by default.  That means, that `ListView` draws only items visible on UI.

Here is MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx)

To be sure what is going on interface (like selection in your case) I'm afraid you don't have any other option then

- or disable UI virtualization (not good)
- or implement `IsSelected` flag on ModelView

Good luck.

Comment: Well i added the IsSelected flag at last, but working with out that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Behavior to Sync the Selected Items to a Collection in Your View Model....

You a ve to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project as well as an alias to it in your Xaml

## Beahvior

```
public class MultiSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            if (SelectedItems != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
                foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

public IList SelectedItems
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectionBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));

private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var behavior = o as MultiSelectionBehavior;
    if (behavior == null)
        return;

    var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (oldValue != null)
    {
        oldValue.CollectionChanged -= behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
        behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= behavior.ListViewSelectionChanged;
    }
    if (newValue != null)
    {
        behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
        {
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }

        behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += behavior.ListViewSelectionChanged;
        newValue.CollectionChanged += behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
    }
}

private bool _isUpdatingTarget;
private bool _isUpdatingSource;

void SourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isUpdatingSource)
        return;

    try
    {
        _isUpdatingTarget = true;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _isUpdatingTarget = false;
    }
}

private void ListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isUpdatingTarget)
        return;

    var selectedItems = this.SelectedItems;
    if (selectedItems == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        _isUpdatingSource = true;

        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            selectedItems.Remove(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            selectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _isUpdatingSource = false;
    }
}

}
```

## Xaml

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectionMode="Extended">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MultiSelectionBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding MySelectedItems}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

`MySelectedItems` is the collection in your ViewModel

Dont forget it initialize ... `MySelectedItems` in your ViewModel....

## Your ViewModel

```
private void ExcludeCurveExecuted(object param)
{                  
    int count =  MySelectedItems.Count;
}
```

Comment: @Mohanavel The Code is already there you just have to use it.... and yes its going to save you a lot of work for the sync Items