# MVVM multiple selection, keep after data reloading

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm using listview that must be able to cope with multiselection. To achieve it I use solution described at [MultiSelection not working in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076665/multiselection-not-working-in-listview) (Ankesh answer). It works fine. In my application some timer is working which retrieves devices status every 10 seconds and it assign ObservableCollection as ItemsSource to my ListView and then my selected rows are deselected.

I thought that when I store selected items before reloading data to temporary variable and assign it later it will work, but I have some problems which I can't diagnose.

This is my code (reloading data block):

```
if (SelectedMachines != null)
{
    foreach (var selectedMachine in SelectedMachines)
    {
        oldSelected.Add(selectedMachine.Clone()); // clone objects
    }
 SelectedMachines.Clear();
 }

Machines = Controller.GetAutomats(); // assign data

if (SelectedMachines != null) // restore selection
{
    foreach (var selectedMachine in oldSelected)
    {
        SelectedMachines.Add(Machines.Where(t => t.Id == selectedMachine.Id).FirstOrDefault());
        // at this point SelectedMachines has same elements count as before assign
    }
}
```

Unfortunately such code clears selection after reloading data.

Comment: 1) Accepted answer from linked question (in particular, `IsSelected` flag in view model) is a right way to go; I wouldn't recommend to use behavior from the 2nd answer; 2) what do you clone objects for, when adding to `oldSelected`? 3) How `Machines` is related to `FullMachines`?

Comment: Ad 1. I would like to avoid IsSelected flag in my model. Ad 2. I'm cloning it because I don't want to store reference to element that can be removed later. Ad 3. It is mistake, it the same element, I corrected my code.